# Where can I get config hotkeys for IDEA like on Windows to Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, hotkeys

Where can I get config hotkeys for Intellij IDEA (OS X) like on Windows?

I want to load ready script of hotkeys to Intellij IDEA (OS X). Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. It's very simple. You can choose the config from Windows in the Preferences. 
Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Keymap:
The field "Keymaps". And here you can choose you config for hotkeys.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0ZZm.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a cheat sheet / reference card [here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).

Challenge! Learn one of these every day until you know them all (takes 2-3 months).

Also check out a plugin called "Key Promoter"

Comment: I have it. But I use both OS. Windows at home and OS X at work. It's not comfortably to use different hotkeys. I want to find ready config of hotkeys.